# Flatten XML Structure (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, xquery

I have the following XML that I pass to a stored procedure via a web service

```
    <Company>
       <Records>
         <Person>
           <ServicePostalCodes>
             <PostalCode>80017</PostalCode>
             <PostalCode>80018</PostalCode>
             <PostalCode>80019</PostalCode>
             <PostalCode>80020</PostalCode>
             <PostalCode>80021</PostalCode>
             <PostalCode>80022</PostalCode>
           </ServicePostalCodes>
          <Employee>
             <EmployeeId>123456-789</EmployeeId>
             <Street1>http</Street1>
             <City>www</City>
             <State>StackOverflow</State>
             <Zip>DotCom</Zip>
          </Employee>
        </Person>
        <Person>
         <ServicePostalCodes>
            <PostalCode>90031</PostalCode>
            <PostalCode>90032</PostalCode>
            <PostalCode>90033</PostalCode>
            <PostalCode>90034</PostalCode>
            <PostalCode>90035</PostalCode>
            <PostalCode>90036</PostalCode>
         </ServicePostalCodes>
         <Employee>
            <EmployeeId>222222-789</EmployeeId>
            <Street1>http</Street1>
            <City>www</City>
            <State>StackOverflow</State>
            <Zip>DotCom</Zip>
         </Employee>
       </Person>
    </Records>
   </Company>
```

I'm looking for a way to "flatten" this into a SQL result set like the following:

```
    Person     |  ServicePostalCode
    123456-789 |  80017
    123456-789 |  80018
    123456-789 |  80019
    222222-789 |  90031
    222222-789 |  90032
    222222-789 |  90033
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe:

```
SELECT
      People.col.value('Employee[1]/EmployeeId[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Person,
      PostalCodes.col.value('(text())[1]','nvarchar(100)')
FROM  
      @xml.nodes('/Company/Records/Person') AS People(col) CROSS APPLY
      col.nodes('ServicePostalCodes/PostalCode') AS PostalCodes(col)
```

Will do what you want assuming your XML is in @xml

Basically what this does is creates a table out of each /Company/Records/Person record, then does a CROSS APPLY (which is similar to a JOIN, but executes row-by-row) to each record in the corresponding ServicePostalCodes/PostalCode record (e.g. it's children).